# CSS menu jumps to the left of page modification?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a pure CSS dropdown menu, but it has one odd bug;
when the page loads, the text in the main menubar is slightly offset to the right.
It jumps back to the left when the page is modified or when a menu item is moused-over.
This includes right-click > inspect element, which makes it really hard to find out what's going on.

Here's an example of it: http://jsfiddle.net/m75p3/1/

As you can see, it's in the wrong position on load, but jumps to the correct one a few milliseconds after. This is because jsfiddle is modifying the page.
If loaded from its own file, it will not exhibit this jumping behaviour until moused-over.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have declared 'position:absolute' on your 'toplink' elements but not given any left value, so their position is determined by their parent's text-align:center rule. When the transition occurs, that disturbs the layout so they move. To fix it you need to declare the li as position:relative, so that it becomes the layout parent, and then set left:0 on the 'toplink' a element.

Addition:
To prevent the text from wrapping in the sub-menus, you can set their white-space to nowrap.

```
#head ul li  {
    position: relative;
    ...
}

.toplink {
    left: 0;
    ...
}

#head li li, #head li li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m75p3/5/

Comment: This _almost_ works, except now strings that are too long for the box don't make it bigger.

Comment: It solves the question that you asked, nothing has changed about the widths, which you have hardcoded.

Comment: it also breaks something I had in effect before. The position:relative; breaks the width of my sub-menus.

Comment: yes, and I marked it as the correct answer. Sorry for not doing it before.